# Add empty column at the end of a CSV file that uses ^A (i.e. \001) as the delimiter?

Tags: shell, csv

Add empty column at the end of a CSV file that uses ^A (i.e. \001) as the delimiter?

Input-file.csv

`cat Input-file.csv`

```
Thomasstackoverflowdellhplenovo
Thomasstackoverflowdellhplenovo
Thomasstackoverflowdellhplenovo
```

`cat -v Input-file.csv`

```
Thomas^Astackoverflow^Adell^Ahp^Alenovo
Thomas^Astackoverflow^Adell^Ahp^Alenovo
Thomas^Astackoverflow^Adell^Ahp^Alenovo
```

Expected Output afer adding empty column at the end

```
Thomas^Astackoverflow^Adell^Ahp^Alenovo^A
Thomas^Astackoverflow^Adell^Ahp^Alenovo^A
Thomas^Astackoverflow^Adell^Ahp^Alenovo^A
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed, you can do `sed 's/$/\x01/' file`.

```
$ sed 's/$/\x01/' Input-file.csv | od -c
0000000   T   h   o   m   a   s 001   s   t   a   c   k   o   v   e   r
0000020   f   l   o   w 001   d   e   l   l 001   h   p   ^   A   l   e
0000040   n   o   v   o 001  \n   T   h   o   m   a   s 001   s   t   a
0000060   c   k   o   v   e   r   f   l   o   w 001   d   e   l   l 001
0000100   h   p 001   l   e   n   o   v   o 001  \n   T   h   o   m   a
0000120   s 001   s   t   a   c   k   o   v   e   r   f   l   o   w 001
0000140   d   e   l   l 001   h   p 001   l   e   n   o   v   o 001  \n
0000160
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response guys, i found the answer

awk -F, '{NF=2}1' OFS="\001" inputfile.csv > outputfile.csv